# R: Plotting panel model predictions using plm & pglm

Tags: r, panel-data, plm

I've created two regression models using a linear panel model with plm, and a generalized panel model using poisson with the pglm package.

```
library(plm); library(pglm)
data(Unions)  # from pglm-package
punions <- pdata.frame(Unions, c("id", "year"))

fit1 <- plm(wage ~ exper + rural + married, data=punions, model="random")
fit2 <- pglm(wage ~ exper + rural + married, data=punions, model="random", family="poisson")
```

I now want to compare the two fits graphically by plotting the fitted values in a set of scatterplots. Preferably along these lines using ggplot2:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(punions, aes(x=exper, y=wage)) +
    geom_point() +
    facet_wrap(rural ~ married)
```

I considered simply using ggplot2's `stat_smooth()`, but (perhaps unsurprisingly) it doesn't seem to recognize the panel format of my data. Manually extracting the predicted values with `predict` also does not seem to work for the pglm-model.

How do I overlay the predicted values for my two panel models in this plot?

Comment: The examples in the middle of [this doc page](http://docs.ggplot2.org/current/geom_abline.html) may be useful to you.

Comment: What are your random effects? Individuals?

Answer (score 8):

Similar to @mtoto, I am also not familiar with either `library(plm)` or `library(pglm)`. But the predict method for `plm` is available, it's just not exported. *Edit: For models produced by `plm::plm()`, there is a `predict` method available since `plm` CRAN release version 2.6-2.*
`pglm` does not have a predict method.

```
R> methods(class= "plm")
[1] ercomp          fixef           has.intercept   model.matrix    pFtest          plmtest         plot            pmodel.response
 [9] pooltest        predict         residuals       summary         vcovBK          vcovHC          vcovSCC        
R> methods(class= "pglm")
no methods found
```

Of note, I do not understand why you are using a Poisson model for the wage data. It's clearly not a Poisson distribution since it takes non-integer values (below). You could try a negative binomial if you wish, though I'm not sure that's available with random effects. But you could use `MASS::glm.nb` for instance.

```
> quantile(Unions$wage, seq(0,1,.1))
         0%         10%         20%         30%         40%         50%         60%         70%         80%         90%        100% 
 0.02790139  2.87570334  3.54965422  4.14864865  4.71605855  5.31824370  6.01422463  6.87414349  7.88514525  9.59904809 57.50431282
```

#### Solution 1: use `plm`

```
punions$p <- predict(fit1, punions)

ggplot(punions, aes(x=exper, y=p)) +
  geom_point() +
  facet_wrap(rural ~ married)
```

#### Solution 2 - `lme4`

Alternatively, you can get similar fits from the `lme4` package, which does have a predict method defined:

```
library(lme4)
Unions$id <- factor(Unions$id)
fit3 <- lmer(wage ~ exper + rural + married + (1|id), data= Unions)
# not run:
fit4 <- glmer(wage ~ exper + rural + married + (1|id), data= Unions, family= poisson(link= "log"))

R> fit1$coefficients
(Intercept)       exper    ruralyes  marriedyes 
  3.7467469   0.3088949  -0.2442846   0.4781113 
R>  fixef(fit3)
(Intercept)       exper    ruralyes  marriedyes 
  3.7150302   0.3134898  -0.1950361   0.4592975
```

I haven't run the poisson models because it's clearly incorrectly specified. You could do some sort of variable transformation to handle it or perhaps a negative binomial. In any case, let's finish the example:

```
# this has RE for individuals, so you do see dispersion based on the RE
Unions$p <- predict(fit3, Unions)
ggplot(Unions, aes(x=exper, y=p)) +
    geom_point() +
    facet_wrap(rural ~ married)
```

[image]

Comment: For models produced by `plm::plm()`, there is a `predict` method available since `plm` version 2.6-2.

Answer (score 2):

I am not familiar with the pglm package, but there seems to be no function similar to `predict()` that will generate a vector of future values from a data frame.

In all other cases (which should be all tbh), you can easily plot this in ggplot, even using facet wrap. You simply add the predictions to the data frame as new column:

```
punions$pred1 <- predict(fit1,punions,class="lm")
```

And then add it as an additional `geom_line()` :

```
    ggplot() + geom_point(data=punions, aes(x=exper, y=wage)) +
    geom_line(data=punions,aes(x=exper, y= pred1), color = "red") +
    facet_wrap(rural ~ married)
```